# how close a.lower() in python to a->lower() in C++

Tags: python

Since variables point to objects in python, I guess, and it is a reference. Suppose `a` is a string and can I fully interpret `a.lower()` in python as a replacement for C/C++ `a->lower()` on a pointer to `char*`? I know these are different languages, but trying to relate similar concepts so that it is easier to understand.

Edit: Suppose I have a class that implements a string that has a lower method.

Answer (score 3):

`char*` does not have a `lower()` method. Your comparison is invalid.

Calling `str.lower()` is like calling `tolower(3)` on each character in turn and returning the new string.

Answer (score 2):

you say:

> Suppose I have a class that implements a string that has a lower
>   method.

but then it gets very difficult to guess what the implementation of the method does.

The main difference you may have in C++ / Python strings is in-place modification: Python strings are not mutable, whereas C++ strings are. So your string.lower() C++ method may be changing the string in place and not returning a new string which is what the Python version does.

E.g. Boost string library has a to_lower() method which does in place modification (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_lower.html)